# Как сделать сортировку массива по ключевому слову

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, список

```
['1_1_Oleg', '1_2_Oleg', '1_3_Oleg', 
 '1_4_Oleg', '1_5_Oleg', '1_6_Oleg', 
 '2_1_Maks', '2_2_Maks', '2_3_Maks', 
 '2_4_Maks']
```

Из массива по форме \

`{Номер поста}` `_` `{Номер фотографии}` `_` `{Имя Актёра}` \

нужно сделать сортировку по `Номеру поста` и `Номеру фотографии`, а потом выводилось `Имя Актёра`

Comment: несколько раз перечитал, так и не понял что именно вам нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если привести все цифры к int, то все отсортируется правильно:

```py
lst = [
    '1_1_Oleg1', 
    '1_2_Oleg', 
    '1_3_Oleg3', 
    '1_4_Oleg2', 
    '1_5_Olega', 
    '1_6_Olegn', 
    '2_4_Maks1',
    '2_1_Maks4', 
    '2_2_Maks2', 
    '11_3_Maks3', 
]

def sortlst(val: str):
  n1, n2, string = val.split('_')
  return int(n1), int(n2), string

print(*sorted(lst, key=sortlst), sep='\n')

# 1_1_Oleg1
# 1_2_Oleg
# 1_3_Oleg3
# 1_4_Oleg2
# 1_5_Olega
# 1_6_Olegn
# 2_1_Maks4
# 2_2_Maks2
# 2_4_Maks1
# 11_3_Maks3
```

Вот так будет выглядеть если использовать строковые значения для сортировки

```py
lst = [
    '1_1_Oleg1', 
    '1_2_Oleg', 
    '1_3_Oleg3', 
    '1_4_Oleg2', 
    '1_5_Olega', 
    '1_6_Olegn', 
    '2_4_Maks1',
    '2_1_Maks4', 
    '2_2_Maks2', 
    '11_3_Maks3', 
]
print(*sorted(lst, key=lambda v: v.split('_')), sep='\n')
# 1_1_Oleg1
# 1_2_Oleg
# 1_3_Oleg3
# 1_4_Oleg2
# 1_5_Olega
# 1_6_Olegn
# 11_3_Maks3
# 2_1_Maks4
# 2_2_Maks2
# 2_4_Maks1
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
_list = [
    '1_1_Oleg1', 
    '1_2_Oleg', 
    '1_3_Oleg3', 
    '1_4_Oleg2', 
    '1_5_Olega', 
    '1_6_Olegn', 
    '2_1_Maks4', 
    '2_2_Maks2', 
    '2_3_Maks3', 
    '2_4_Maks1'
]

print(*sorted(_list, key=lambda v: (v[0], v[2], v[4:])), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Всем хорош вариант но я бы поправил немоного лямбду на `print(*sorted(_list, key=lambda v: v.split('_')), sep='\n')` поскольку если нумерация пойдет на десятки или сотни Ваш способ даст сбой. Но для совсем корректной работы не хватает приведения первых двух значений ключа к int

Comment: @Namerek да, вы конечно правы, но я просто продемонстрировал один из  вариантов с использованием функции `lambda`

Answer (score 0):

> Из массива по форме {Номер поста} _ {Номер фотографии} _ {Имя Актёра}
> нужно сделать сортировку по Номеру поста и Номеру фотографии

```
arr = ['1_1_Oleg', '1_2_Oleg', '1_3_Oleg', '1_4_Oleg', '1_5_Oleg', '1_6_Oleg', '2_1_Maks', '2_2_Maks', '2_3_Maks', '2_4_Maks']

res = sorted(list(map(lambda obj: (int(obj.split('_')[0]), int(obj.split('_')[1]), obj.split('_')[2]), arr)))

for obj in res:
    print(*obj)
```

> а потом выводилось Имя Актёра

концовка совсем запутала :)

в общем вот вам код сортировки по номеру поста и номеру фотографии

Comment: фуфуфу так делать... я конечно понимаю, что сейчас экономия ресурсов отошла даже не на второй план, но проделывать одну и туже операцию несколько раз для получения одного и того-же результата, это как-то не "комильфо".

Comment: @Namerek, согласен что фуфуфу, не хотел просто функцию отдельную делать :), а так я всеми руками за разумную экономию вычислительных ресурсов,